# Google Autocomplete place country filter not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter?.country = "AU"
autocompleteController.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I need only filter data for Australia so I want to filter data by country.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The autocompleteFilter property is nil by default, so the line

```
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter?.country = "AU"
```

doesn't do anything. Do it like this instead:

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.country = "AU"
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

Comment: Hi @AndrewR, We are using  GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config). Can we set filter with GMSPlacePickerViewController ?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 1):

```css
GMSAutocompleteViewController *controller = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc]init];
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc]init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    filter.country = @"IN";
    controller.autocompleteFilter = filter;
```